# error in code comparing elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

Im a student programmer so only been studying since september. Had an assignment this week to read in data from a text file called datingdata.txt and create a class for the information storing each persons info in a position of an array. The data was in the format 'George Robson       M 38 11000' where the name was up to 20 characters. Then we had to compare each person for matches, where they were of an opposite sex, within 5 years of each other in age and had at least 3 common interests (the 1 meaning they were interested in that activity and 0 if not). I have got it working up to the nested for loops at the end and have a feeling I am missing brackets because it keeps coming up with an error that it cannot find symbols. Any help?

```
    import java.io.*;
    import static java.lang.Math.*;
    class PersonInfo
   {
    String name;
    char sex;
    int age;
    String interest;

    public void setname (String anyName)
       { name = anyName; }

    public void setsex (char anysex)
       { sex = anysex; }

    public void setage (int anyage)
       { age = anyage; }

    public void setinterest (String anyinterest)
       { interest = anyinterest; }

    public String getName ()
       { return name; }

    public char getsex ()
       { return sex; }

    public int getage ()
    {return age;  }

    public String getinterest ()
    {return interest;    }

    void print ()
       {
        System.out.println(name + " " + sex + " " + age + " " + interest);
       }

    PersonInfo (String name, char sex, int age, String interest)
       {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
        this.interest = interest;
       }
    }

    class Practical6
      {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {
        //read in file
        BufferedReader fileInput;
        fileInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("datingdata.txt"));

        //create an array for storing each persons information
        PersonInfo[] People = new PersonInfo[20];

        //fields to use in creating PersonInfo
        String name;
        char sex;
        int age;
        String interest;

        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;

        //read in each line and store in an array
        while (fileInput.ready ())                                  
           {                                                    
            String information;
            information = fileInput.readLine ();                                
           // System.out.println (information);
            name = information.substring(0,20);
            sex = information.charAt(20);
            age = Integer.parseInt(information.substring(22,24));   
            interest = information.substring(25,30);
            People[i]= new PersonInfo (name, sex, age, interest);
            i++;                                
           } 
        fileInput.close(); 

        //pring out the array

        for (int j = 0; j < People.length; j++)
            People[j].print();


        //go through each element of array and compare to another record for a match
        for (int k = 0; k < People.length; k++)
            for (int l = 0; l <People.length; l++)
            if (People[k].getsex() != People[l].getsex())
                if(math.abs(People[k].getage()-People[l].getage()) <=5)
                {for(int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
                    if((People[k].getinterest.charAt(m)=='1')  && (People[l].getinterest.charAt(m)=='1'));
                            count++;
                            if(count==3)
                                System.out.println(People[k].getname + " is a match with " + People[l].getname);
                }

            }
            }
```

Comment: You're definitely missing some braces at the bottom in your big for/if block.  I recommend using a good text editor that does brace match highlighting to help with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int k = 0; k < People.length; k++)
    for (int l = 0; l <People.length; l++)
    if (People[k].getsex() != People[l].getsex())
        if(Math.abs(People[k].getage()-People[l].getage()) <=5)
        {for(int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
            if((People[k].getinterest().charAt(m)=='1')  && (People[l].getinterest().charAt(m)=='1'));
                    count++;
                    if(count==3)
                        System.out.println(People[k].getName() + " is a match with " + People[l].getName());
        }
```

some syntax error:
1. Math.abs() instead of math.abs()
2. getinterest() instead of getinterest
3. getName() instead of getname